# Can't execute javascript in the webview

Tags: java, android

I've tried so many things and it seems that nothing is working...
In every one solution I see that I can enable javascript and execute whatever I want after the webpage is loaded in the webview.
However my code seems to be wrong and I really can`t see why..

Tried to make a new class and override the `onPageFinished()`

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:$(document).ready(function() { $('.logo').css('display','none'); });");
}
```

Not working!

Tried to hardcode it :

```
final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:<script>$(document).ready(function() {             $('.pages').css('display','none!important'); });</script>");
    }
});
webview.loadUrl("https://zdravenmonitor.bg/");
```

Also not working..

What its problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { $(document).ready(function() { $('.logo').css('display','none'); }); })()");
```

Comment: Thanks man.Thats working.I don`t see the difference but it really works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Define a function in your javascript file as

```
function finishPage(){
    //Do your work
}
```

And call it from WebChromeClient as:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:finishPage()");
```

Hope this helps.